# Azure blob as Image Windows Forms

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, azure, azure-blob-storage

In my application I am be able to upload some images to my blob storage on Windows Azure. And now im developing the second part of my application, retrieve the images from the Azure server, and show them in a picturebox.

I have tried several things:

```
listboxPictures.Items.Clear();
iTotalPictures = 0;
CloudBlobClient blobClient =
    new CloudBlobClient("http://ferryjongmans.blob.core.windows.net/",
        new StorageCredentialsSharedAccessSignature(signature));
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
CloudBlobDirectory direct = container.GetDirectoryReference(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
BlobRequestOptions options = new BlobRequestOptions();
options.UseFlatBlobListing = true;
options.BlobListingDetails = BlobListingDetails.Snapshots;
foreach (var blobItem in direct.ListBlobs(options))
{
    listboxPictures.Items.Add(blobItem.Uri.ToString());
    iTotalPictures ++;
    lblTotal.Text = "Total frames: "+Convert.ToString(iTotalPictures);
    pictureBox1.ImageLocation = blobItem.Uri.ToString(); // This is the display box, this works only with public settings on the container
}
```

This works, but only when the container is public (setting in Azure control panel). But I want to get my images when I have my container on private.

Who can help me please?

(I hope the description is clearly enough)

[Application when my blobcontainer settings are on public](http://www.cindesbetondesign.nl/Application.png)
[Application when my blobcontainer settings are on private](http://www.cindesbetondesign.nl/application2.png)

Comment: What is the exception you are getting?

Comment: I don't get an exception, but it cant load the image because the blob URI isn't public when my container settings are on private. (in the picturebox i get a little "x" what says "I cant load the image"). So I think i need an alternative way to show my image in the picturebox and not via the blob URI... And I don't know where to start.. When my container is on public, works everything fine... But this application is for a company and it will progress security camera snapshots.. So i think its important to set the container settings on private and do it via an another way...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure that your SAS signature has "**Read**" permission defined ("List" permission will only allow listing blobs in a blob container). Then replace the following line of code:

```
pictureBox1.ImageLocation = blobItem.Uri.ToString();
```

With:

```
pictureBox1.ImageLocation = blobItem.Uri.ToString() + signature;
```

The reason you're not able to see pictures is because the URI you're getting for the blob does not have a SAS component attached to it.

Comment: Wow haha i'm kicking myself... Thank you for this answer! IT WORKS!